# Is there a way to merge these two tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I have two tables :

```
question_likes:

question_id references question(id)
user_id references users(id)
primary key (user_id, question_id)


answer_likes:

answer_id references answers(id)
user_id references users(id)
primary key (user_id, answer_id)
```

A colleague suggested that I can use inheritance in Postgres to merge these into one table.

Is there a way to design this requirement?

Comment: Inheritance make sense in case if there are several common columns in tables. Using inheritance only for one column is superfluously IMO. Also read about [inheritance caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What exactly is your current design? What is a subtype of what? (Questions & answers as posts?) What does "merge" mean? Please go to the documentation & show us what you are able to design & where you are stuck. Please explain yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't need that certainly I believe. You can perform a `JOIN` between the tables and display the required fields like below. Or, create a view with the below SQL statement.

```
select q.question_id,
q.user_id,
a.answer_id 
from  question_likes q
join answer_likes a on a.user_id = q.user_id;
```

(or) a `full outer join` as suggested in comment by klin

```
from  question_likes
full join answer_likes using(user_id);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, these two tables are not related via a foreign key, so how does a join help here?

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat, you haven't provided all your table structure but from post it can be seen that both table has `user_id` common column which references users(id). And so you can join on them. `join` can also be done on common column between the tables

Comment: @Rahul - rather `full join answer_likes using(user_id);`

Comment: @klin, perfect considering what OP says *merging* both tables but not sure if OP specifically looking for `Inheritance` which anyway have no idea about. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat PKs, FKs and other constraints are not needed for querying. They just allow the DBMS to disallow states you tell it are impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
    like_id            serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int
);

CREATE TABLE question_likes (
    question_id int,
    primary key (user_id, question_id)
) INHERITS (likes);

CREATE TABLE answer_likes (
    answer_id int,
    primary key (user_id, answer_id)
) INHERITS (likes);
```

Than `merging` can be done using `UNION`

```
SELECT like_id, user_id, question_id, null as answer_id FROM question_likes q
UNION 
SELECT like_id, user_id, null as question_id, answer_id FROM answer_likes a;
```

What exactly do you want to achieve?